# How to print outputs of a loop horizontally in R?

Tags: r, loops

I'm running a code and getting output like this:

```
  X.0.0189575409702549
1          -0.01895754
2          -0.14051254
3          -0.04389737
4          -0.06815956
5          -0.12350667
6          -0.07588814
```

whereas the required output should be like this:

```
[1] -0.01895754 -0.14051254 -0.04389737 -0.06815956 -0.12350667 -0.07588814
```

My code is as follows:

```
corr<-function(directory, threshold=0){
  files_list<-list.files(directory, full.names = T)
  dat<-data.frame()
  final<-data.frame()
  rcor<-c()
for (i in 1:332) {
  dat<-read.csv(files_list[i])
  comp<-sum(complete.cases(dat))
   if (comp>threshold){
     x<-dat[complete.cases(dat),"sulfate"]
     y<-dat[complete.cases(dat),"nitrate"]
                       rcor<-cor(x,y)
                      final<-rbind(final,rcor)
                      }
  } 
final
}
```

I have tried cbind() but it gives me a lot of NAs. Im totally lost, really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: `final[[1]]` should work.

Comment: Is `t(final)` what you want? Is this about *printing* the output or shaping it?

Answer (score 0):

```
corr<-function(directory, threshold=0){
  files_list<-list.files(directory, full.names = T)
  dat<-data.frame()
  final<-data.frame()
  rcor<-c()
for (i in 1:332) {
  dat<-read.csv(files_list[i])
  comp<-sum(complete.cases(dat))
   if (comp>threshold){
     x<-dat[complete.cases(dat),"sulfate"]
     y<-dat[complete.cases(dat),"nitrate"]
                       rcor<-cor(x,y)
                      final<-rbind(final,rcor)
                      }
  } 
as.vector(final) 
}
```